# Массив констант

Tags: c#, массивы, константа

Не могу вспомнить как сделать, мне нужно из БД прочитать константы и записать их в статичный массив что бы обращаться потом там где надо, я хочу обращаться не по индексу елемента а по имени. Ну типо `arr["maxLeight"].value` и получить 30 в результат к примеру.

Бд выглядит так :

Заголовок - code     |uvalue
Значения  - maxLeight|30

```
   using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GlobalVariable.connectionString))
{
    cn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = cn;

            cmd.CommandText = "select * from constants";
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {

            }

    }
}
```

прошу подсказать.

Comment: Похоже, Вам нужен обычный `Dictionary`. Причем здесь БД - не очень понятно.

Comment: @alexolut, при том, что там хранятся значения? :-D

Comment: @Grundy ну можно ещё про жёсткий диск тогда рассказать, на котором эта база хранится. Но к проблеме это отношения по-прежнему никакого иметь не будет.

Comment: @Grundy в БД хранятся значения констант, я хочу при запуске программы вычитывать их и распихать по статичным переменным что сейчас и делаю, но мне это не очень нравится, кажется через массив будет правильней.

Comment: @Winteriscoming, для обращения по имени, правильней через словарь

Comment: Тогда это 2 раздельных вопроса: "Как получить данные из базы?" и "Как хранить и использовать набор глобальных значений?". У вас проблемы и с тем, и с тем? Значит стоит задавать их по раздельности.

Comment: @vp_arth, тут скорее вопрос, как из базы положить в словарь

Comment: @vp_arth я вроде выложил кусок которым достаю из базы.

Comment: *Значит с этим вопросом у вас проблем нет - можно исключить лишние сущности из вопроса.* Я придираюсь, скорее всего :)

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, запрос возвращает два строковых поля на строку:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  connection.Open();

  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT name, val FROM constants", connection))
  {
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        // Добавляем запись в словарь
        dictionary.Add(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Сам словарь может быть полем некоего Singleton, или быть глобальным. Также вы можете передавать его как параметр туда, где он нужен(DI).

---

Для словаря `<string, int>`, нужно пользоваться соответствующими методами интерпретации результатов запроса(GetInt32, например):

```
  Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  // ...
  dictionary.Add(reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt32(1));
```